# Is it a good idea to cache a raw pointer along with its owning shared_ptr for better access performance?

Tags: c++, performance, shared-ptr

Consider this scenario:

```
class A
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> _b;
    B* _raw;

    A(std::shared_ptr<B> b)
    {
         _b = b;
         _raw = b.get();
    }

    void foo()
    {
         // Use _raw instead of _b
         // avoid one extra indirection / memory jump
         // and also avoid polluting cache
    }
};
```

I know that technically it works and offers a slight performance advantage (I tried it). (EDIT: False conclusion).
But my question is: Is it conceptually wrong? Is it bad practice? And why?
And if not why is this hack not more commonly used?

Here is a minimal reproducible example comparing raw pointer access to shared_ptr access:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct timer final
{
    timer()
        : start{std::chrono::system_clock::now()}
    { }

    void elapsed()
    {
        auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::chrono::duration<double>(now - start).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start;
};

struct A
{
    size_t a [2097152];
};

int main()
{
    size_t data_size = 2097152;
    size_t count = 10000000000;

    // Using Raw pointer
    A * pa = new A();
    timer t0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
        pa->a[i % data_size] = i;
    t0.elapsed();

    // Using shared_ptr
    std::shared_ptr<A> sa = std::make_shared<A>();
    timer t1;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
        sa->a[i % data_size] = i;
    t1.elapsed();
}
```

Output:

3.98586 seconds

4.10491 seconds

I ran this multiple times and the results are consistent.

EDIT: As per the consensus in the answers, the above experiment is invalid. Compilers are way smarter than they appear.

Comment: What was your measurement criteria? Can you show your measurement code and your compile options? I'm curious if it's actually faster when not in debug.

Comment: One downside is your object is now 4/8 bytes larger, which can matter depending on the number of them you have.  You also introduce a potential source of bugs by possibly getting the initialization order wrong.  Could you provide the example you used to benchmark the performance?  I ask because micro benchmarking is hard and is often not done correctly.

Comment: I didn't exactly try this particular use case, but I just finished refactoring a class and replacing all shared_ptr with raw pointers and it made a difference. In that class I don't move or send shared_ptrs around, just accessing them so I assumed that must be the case. I will benchmark a minimal case if the benefit ends up being disputed but I thought it was trivial?

Comment: A simple dereference of the shared pointer using `->` shouldn't be any slower than the raw pointer when using optimized code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the timing difference.

Comment: "I tried it" What exactly did you try and how did you measure in detail? I see no reason why any advanced optimizer - even without a higher aggressivity level - should not be able to achieve the raw pointer access performance these days.

Comment: I updated the question with a measurement example

Comment: @FrancoisZard the shown code will be slightly slower for `shared_ptr` with no optimizations. With optimizations, the compiler optimizes everything away. And your measurement is meaningless. Besides that, it doubts, that dereferencing a  `shared_ptr` is slower and a raw pointer (if the compiler works correctly), because each `shared_ptr` holds the memory address to the managed object and the location from where to read that address is known, (it is either the location of the `shared_ptr` itself - like for the raw pointer - or a fixed offset) so there shouldn't be any difference regarding that.

Comment: There is no performance difference accessing a shared pointer, so no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer proves your test is invalid (correct performance measurements in C++ are quite hard since there are lots of pitfalls) and as a result you come to invalid conclusions.

Take a look on this [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hb4qPT).

`for` loop for first version:

```
.L39:
        mov     rdx, rax
        and     edx, 2097151
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp+0+rdx*8], rax
        add     rax, 1
        cmp     rax, rcx
        jne     .L39
```

`for` loop for second version:

```
.L40:
        mov     rdx, rax
        and     edx, 2097151
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp+16+rdx*8], rax
        add     rax, 1
        cmp     rax, rcx
        jne     .L40
```

I do not see a difference! Results should be exactly same.

So I suspect that you have done measurements when building in Debug configuration.

Here is version where [you can compare this](https://godbolt.org/z/TcYTKf)

What is more interesting [clang is able to optimize away](https://godbolt.org/z/5839z5) `for` loop if shared pointer is not used. It noticed there is no viable results of this loop and just remove it. So if you used release configuration compiler just outsmart you.

Bottom line:

- shared_ptr do not provide overhead
- when checking performance you must compile with optimizations enabled
- you must also ensure if test code was not optimized away to be sure that results are valid.

Here is [proper test](https://quick-bench.com/q/mK2aT2WRXSQ4terVnBqHSJkGj1A) written using google benchmark and test results for both cases are exactly the same.

Comment: I added arbitrary assignment of the array values on purpose precisely to try and stop the compiler from optimizing the loops away. I guess the compiler is far smarter than I thought it was, judging by how it chokes on a semicolon :)

Answer (score 2):

A `shared_ptr` internally looks roughly like this:

```
template <typename _Tp>
struct shared_ptr {
    T *_M_ptr;
    control_block *cb;
}
```

So one member (`_M_ptr`) points to the managed object and one pointer to the control block (that is used for reference counting, and locking).

The `oeprator->` will look something like this:

```
_Tp* operator->() const {
   return _M_ptr;
}
```

Because the location of `_M_ptr` within `shared_ptr` is known, the compiler can directly retrieve the memory location from where to read the memory address stored in `_M_ptr` without the indirection.

If `T *_M_ptr` is the first member of `shared_ptr`(Which is indeed the case for `libstdc++`) a compiler could change this code:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> sa = std::make_shared<A>();
sa->a[0] = 1;
```

To something that would be similar to this:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> sa = std::make_shared<A>();
(*reinterpret_cast<A**>(&sa))->a[0] = 1;
```

And `reinterpret_cast` is a no-opt (won't create any machine code).

So in most cases, there won't be a difference between dereferencing a `shared_ptr` or a raw pointer. You might be able to construct a case where the memory address of a raw pointer is sorely stored in a register, and the same thing might not be possible for `_M_ptr` of `shared_ptr`, but that would IMHO be a really artificial example.

Regarding your performance test:

The shown code will be slightly slower for `shared_ptr` with no optimizations active because there the indirection over `operator->()` won't be optimized away. With optimizations on, the compiler might optimize - for the given example - everything away and your measurement can be meaningless.

> And if not why is this hack not more commonly used?

In many cases, you use `shared_ptr` only to manage the ownership. When working on the object that is managed by a shared pointer, you often pass the object itself (by reference, or pointer) to another function that does not need ownership (`void do_something_with_object(A *ptr) {…}` and a call `do_something_with_object(sa.get())`) so even if there is a performance impact for a certain stdlib implementation, this won't manifest in most of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it conceptually wrong?

In general, it's not that wrong a priori to have internal supporting objects/helpers in order to achieve required performance goals. Caches for instance are the most popular example I guess. But here for your particular example, I tend to say, it's conceptually wrong even for the case of a slightly better performance (which I doubt at latest when significance is the keyword), since it's not really an internal quality since the raw pointer you use is not an internal of the shared_ptr. The issue I see here especially is the fact, that you duplicate responsibilites since you don't trust a well established standard class here for the sake of a minimal better performance. In software design, the keyword here besides single responsibility is proportionality. You have to duplicate semantics here for all relevant places (Copy/Move constructors), you have to think twice in terms of exception safety, you have to think about that aspect again and again if your class expands and so on. And it will become quite unintelligibly for other developers being faced with your code due to the entangled responsibilites.

A word about shared_ptr's performance:

SharedPtr-dereferencing within memory.h for my current VS 2019 looks like this:

```
template<class _Ty2 = _Ty,
    enable_if_t<!is_array_v<_Ty2>, int> = 0>
    _NODISCARD _Ty2 * operator->() const noexcept
    {   // return pointer to resource
    return (get());
    }
```

And get() directly returns the raw pointer. So why should any common compiler's optimizer not be able to inline the hell out of this?

Comment: I was thinking maybe CPU cache is affected somehow?
Example: a vector of shared_ptr vs a vector of raw pointers. Iterating over the raw pointers will surely be faster than iterating over the shared_ptrs. For one, the extra 8 bytes for reference counting would pollute the cache, not to mention all the copying that happen under the hood?

Comment: @FrancoisZard If your loop creates copies (or needs to create those) then you have a design problem. `8 bytes for reference counting would pollute the cache` they would only be used if a copy of the `shared_ptr` is done when you iterator over the array. `for( auto &sa : vector_of_sa)` won't create copies, so reference counting won't happen.

Comment: @FrancoisZard, of course, there are propable differences for cache-line behavior between vectors of raw and sharedPtrs, but they are almost always irrelevant here I guess since you do not circumvent the "inner" cause of possible performance drops here: Nonlocal heap memory distribution in general. BTW: This is actually not related to your actual question from this thread.

Comment: @Secundi Not directly related. But back to my case, turns out I had a vector of objects containing shared_ptrs. I'm still not sure why I got a significant speedup when I replaced the shared_ptrs with raw pointers. But I guess we've ruled out the case of shared_ptr dereferencing being the cause, so the initial question of caching a raw pointer along with the shared_ptr is indeed invalid. Perhaps I'm iterating over the vector by value, which is causing the shared_ptr to be copied needlessly.. It's the first thing I'll check tomorrow. But thanks!

Comment: @FrancoisZard , yes I guess your issue here might be a hard copy each time as t.niese mentioned. For possible cache-line issues in general, there exist several techniques to improve the performance of loops but for them, the actual context is relevant and a deeper data dependency/locality analysis required. Correct performance analysis and according improvement solutions are often not that trivial as one might think they are.